# issue to update a Boolean value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In my flask app, i create two models, Car and Place.
Issue is that Place model which contain Boolean value isn't updated same time when a new car is added.

I already created two models (Car and Place).

My models (Car and Place models)

```
class Car(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    mark = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=False, nullable=False)
    model = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=False, nullable=False)
    color = db.Column(db.String(16), unique=False, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

```
class Place(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    numb = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)
    is_available = db.Column(db.Boolean())
```

Places routes

```
def make_a_place_unavailable(the_place):
    place_concerned = Place.query.filter_by(numb=the_place).first()
    place_concerned.is_available = False
```

Cars routes

```
from project.cars.forms import AdmitCarForm
from project.models import Car, Place
from project import db
from project.places.routes import make_a_place_unavailable

@cars.route('/c_car', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def c_car():
    form = AdmitCarForm()
    available_places = []
    places = Place.query.filter_by(is_available=True)

    # fill out available places list
    for available_place in places:
        available_places.append(available_place)

    # redirect user to home page if all places are unavailable
    if len(available_places) == 0 :
        flash('All places are unavailable. Remove a car or wait')
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
    else:
        # choose a random available place to park car
        choosen_place = randint(1, len(available_places))

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            # add car to database
            car = Car(
                mark = form.mark.data,
                model = form.model.data,
                color = form.color.data,
                user_id = current_user.id
            )
            db.session.add(car)

            # make place unavailable
            make_a_place_unavailable(choosen_place)

            # add car to database
            db.session.commit()

            flash(f'Car on parking!')
            return redirect(url_for('main.home'))

    return render_template('c_car.html', form=form, choosen_place=choosen_place)
```

The result is that in database when a new car added by form in template, only car is added and the selected place isn't updated in database.
What i want is when i add a new car by a form, place which is indicated be updated.

Comment: Is there a `db.session.commit()` that you're not showing? `db.session.add()` by itself isn't sufficient.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith there is a call to `db.session.commit()`, right after the call to `make_a_place_unavailable()`.

Comment: oh, right. scroll down. my bad. in `make_place_unavailable`, add `db.session.add(place_concerned)`

Comment: In `make_a_place_unavailable()` the place is retrieved by query, so it should already be in the session, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not directly answering your question, but I'd like to suggest that you don't need the `is_available` field.

With the use of `relationship()` properties on your models you can easily tell if a `Place` is available or not, but also you can see which `Car` is in the `Place`, and easily find which `Place` a `Car` is in.

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class Car(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    mark = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=False, nullable=False)
    model = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=False, nullable=False)
    color = db.Column(db.String(16), unique=False, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    # new relationship fields
    place = db.relationship('Place', back_populates='car')
    user = db.relationship('User')


class Place(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # As numb is not nullable, and must be unique, you could consider
    # removing the `id` column above and making `numb` primary key.
    numb = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)

    # new column
    car_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('car.id'))

    # new relationship
    car = db.relationship('Car', back_populates='place', uselist=False)
```

I've annotated the models where I've made changes, also I removed `Place.is_available`.

Here I create some places and a user for testing:

```py
# add some places
db.session.add_all([
    Place(id=1, numb=1),
    Place(id=2, numb=2),
    Place(id=3, numb=3)
])
# create a user
me = User()
db.session.add(me)
db.session.commit()
```

Now, create a car and put it in a Place:

```py
#  instead of query by `is_available`, query for spaces without cars
places = Place.query.filter_by(car=None).all()
print(places)  # [<Place 1>, <Place 2>, <Place 3>]

# create a Car
car = Car(mark='mark', model='model', color='green', user=me)

# put car in a random place, random.choice will select a space
# from the list for you
car.place = random.choice(places)
db.session.commit()

# then we can easily find out if a place is available:
for place in places:
    print(f'{place} is available?', not place.car)
# <Place 1> is available? False
# <Place 2> is available? True
# <Place 3> is available? True

# given a Place, we can easily see the exact car parked there:
for place in places:
    print(f'{place.car} in {place}')
# <Car 1> in <Place 1>
# None in <Place 2>
# None in <Place 3>

# and given a car we can see exactly where it's parked
print(car.place)
# <Place 1>
```